# Tried all related - New blank file missing

Tags: nautilus, templates

Can't right click add new file Ubuntu 18.4

I have no Templates folder (English installation)

so I make one in home and `touch /home/Templates/Empty\ Document`

```
xdg-user-dir TEMPLATES
/root
```

I made templates also in root and also put a Empty Document in root directly

I `nano  ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and added XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="/home/Templates"

tried it with root also.

I can't find anything else to try in related questions. Does anyone know how to fix it?

## EDIT

For now I have just made a file called 'Blank' on my desktop that I can copy 'n' paste.
#HackerMan